# How to minify gulp-webpack file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, compression, gulp, webpack

Have a follow situation:

```
gulp.task('webpack', function(cb) {
  gulp.src('webpack-init.js')
    .pipe(webpack({
      output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
      },
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./client/js'));

  cb();
});
```

All ok, but i want to minify output file.

If i use gulp-uglify directly -

```
.pipe(webpack(...))
.pipe(uglify().on('error', gutil.log))
.pipe(gulp.dest('./client/js'));
```

have an error: "Unexpected token: punc ())]" and others of that ilk.

Comment: Where do you get the errors?

Comment: In a console. When uglify is trying to compress bundle.js .

Comment: What's the full output?

Comment: Save console message: http://txs.io/dd3b

Comment: It sounds like WebPack isn't outputting Javascript.

Comment: I have big files on the input - ReactJS and some of his components. 
Output must be a JS file - it is an usual file for the client side.

I don't know what is the real reason of the error. =(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found a solution. We can use normal version of webpack (not just gulp-webpack) to provide plugin include capability:

```
var gulpWebpack = require('gulp-webpack'),
  webpack = require('webpack');

gulp.task('webpack', function() {
  gulp.src('webpack-init.js')

    .pipe(gulpWebpack({
      output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
      },
      plugins: [new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()],
    }, webpack))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./client/js'));
});
```